Why does emoji U+1F60A contain a new line character in UTF-16 when reading it?
We have a file that, when opened with normal file readers, such as Notepad++, the emoji is rendered successfully and no extra new lines are added.
The problem we are facing is that, when opening the same file with Python, the UTF-16 bytes are divided into two lines, messing up our Big Data Processing Framework that reads the file in parallel.
We need to understand what makes it clear to Notepad++ that there is not a real new line in the sequence =\xd8\n\xde so that we can adjust our custom file reader.

STEPS TO REPRODUCE

Copy this emoji  to an empty file and add a new line.

Save the file and open it with Python in bytes format:
# Open the file as bytes:
with open("file_name.csv", "rb") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)


You find there is an extra newline character in the middle of the emoji:
b'\xff\xfe=\xd8\n'
b'\xde\r\x00\n'
b'\x00'




Open file in real hex editor (HxD for example) to see what the file actually contains.

The UTF-8 bytes of U+1F60A actually are (hexadecimal) f0 9f 98 8a. Note that this does not contain the byte 0A aka \n but 8A.
The UTF-16 (big endian) two-byte chars are: d83d de0a.
The UTF-16LE (little endian) two-byte chars are: 3dd8 0ade.
And here is the error: there is a byte 0a, but the encoding used to read the file is wrong, you are using a byte encoding or such, so it doesn't handle the 0a correctly.

The rest of the real file is in utf-16, that's true. Is there any way we can distiguish "real" newlines from "fake" newlines? Pandas reads these files correctly even if they are utf-16 instead of utf-8

@rodvictor There are no fake newlines. Python simply displays byte 0x0A as \n because it is shorter to do so. If you want to read Unicode characters correctly in Python, why are you opening the file in binary mode in Python, instead of UTF-16 text mode?

@user694733 indeed. One might also note that UTF-8 with its usage of the high bit prevents any mix up.

You can see from the bytes posted on the question that the file has a UTF-16LE BOM at the front.

for line in f, when f is opened in binary mode, is going to read until an 0x0A byte (dislpayed as \n) for each "line", which seems to be the source of the confusion.
